# Outlook web add in suddenly not appearing in Android Outlook app

Tags: javascript, outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I have ran into a problem where a live version of our Outlook add in has dissappeared from users phones when using Android. We reverted to an older Outlook APK on Android as a test and all worked fine, the add in appears. But on the latest version of Outlook on Android, the add in isnt visible. It is also worth noting that it appears fine on iOS and always has.

I am looking for any insight into this and if this is a known problem

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been fixed and deployed from our side.
Please check with the latest build of Microsoft Outlook for Android, from the play store.